# Reviewing my previous questions

Tags: support, questions

How do I view my questions that are tagged with a certain tag?
Example: All the questions that I've asked that are tagged jQuery-mobile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried clicking the [jquery-mobile](/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile) tag located at the bottom of your profile page? This will list all of your posts with that tag. You can do that with any of the tags listed at the bottom of your profile page (unlike the ones listed beneath each question on your profile page, which link to the tag proper).

It's actually a short cut for a search construct, `user:`, which lets you search for posts from a specific user. You can specify the user ID, or just `me` to refer to yourself. So in this example, the search would be [`user:me [jquery-mobile]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+%5Bjquery-mobile%5D).

Find out about all the cool search operators on our [Search Help Page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=), which you can use to further refine your search with, for example, `is:question` to specify only questions or `votes:1` to only find questions with at least one upvote.

Comment: Thanks Grace!  I have a lot to learn.